# Stop MediaPlayer file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'd just like to stop my MediaPlayer file and I really don't understand why is that so complicated. I have this method to start to music:

```
 public void startMusic() {
    mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.zenenegy);
        mediaPlayer1.start();
        mediaPlayer1.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
        mediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
        play = true;
    }
```

And I'd like to stop music with this method:

```
  public void stopMusic(){
    mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.zenenegy);
    if(play){
        mediaPlayer1.stop();
        mediaPlayer1.reset();
        mediaPlayer1.release();
        mediaPlayer1 = null;
        play = false;
    }
```

When I call the startMusic method the music starts but when I call the stopMusic method then nothing happens.If anyone knows how to do that please response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.zenenegy);
```

On this line you are creating a new `MediaPlayer` object and you lose the old object reference (it will continue playing until gc). Use same object, as listed below

```
 public void stopMusic(){
    if (mediaPlayer1 != null){
      if(mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer1.stop();
        mediaPlayer1.reset();
        mediaPlayer1.release();
        mediaPlayer1 = null;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are again creating `MediaPlayer` instance and stopping the new instance. But what you need to do is to stop the existing `MediaPlayer` instance which is running and playing audio. Change your stopMusic() -

```
public void stopMusic(){

    if(play && mediaPlayer1 != null){
        mediaPlayer1.stop();
        mediaPlayer1.reset();
        mediaPlayer1.release();
        mediaPlayer1 = null;
        play = false;
    }
```